# Reading pdf files using mozilla pdf.js from remote internet source on an android app

Tags: javascript, android, pdf

I have been looking for some solutions for this, i got one here - [Show PDF file in Android WebView using mozilla pdf.js Android API Level below 19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278813/show-pdf-file-in-android-webview-using-mozilla-pdf-js-android-api-level-below-19)

but then here he tries to open a local file, is there a way I can open files placed on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must enable CORS on your server http://enable-cors.org/server.html After that pdf.js could open file from your server as well as local file. Another way is to download file from server and open it locally.