# PDF attachment not opening in android

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-webview

I'm using web-view in an android application. In that application I have to view attached PDF and images. When I click image file it's opening fine, but when I click PDFs it's not opening.

Comment: Webview view html pages.  Not pdfs.  If you want to view a pdf, you need to have an app on the phone that does that.  Its not built in functionality.

Comment: For pdf files, you'll have to create your own custom pdf reader or you can use other apps for it.

Answer (score 0):

As said you need to use a native pdf renderer like [RadaeePDF SDK](http://www.radaeepdf.com/) for example, or you can try (https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) inside the webview.

Rendering using JS should work well on the webview of the versions 4.4 and 5.x, For earlier versions you can check [Show PDF file in Android WebView using mozilla pdf.js Android API Level below 19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278813/show-pdf-file-in-android-webview-using-mozilla-pdf-js-android-api-level-below-19/29384599#29384599)