# load pdf from url in PDFView

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf

I want to load pdf from url and I'm using [PDFViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) library for this. But, it is showing blank when opening my app. :(
I want your help.

This is my code:

```java
        PDFView pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
            pdfView.fromUri(Uri.parse("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pdff-69823.appspot.com/o/ehp1.pdf?alt=media&token=9bb1792e-0787-461c-a6a8-1be6724be93f")).load();
```

And, this is my XML for this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
        android:id="@+id/pdfView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And, I'm using this dependency:

```
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1'
```

Comment: Method fromUri():  Use URI as the pdf source, for use with content providers

Comment: @young , I didn't get that. Could you please explain more?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?  If yes, can you please share your answer as I am also facing the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why I cannot open PDF from URL?

Downloading files is long running process which must be aware of Activity lifecycle, must support some configuration, data cleanup and  caching, so creating such module will probably end up as new library.

I think this library only support files that are already exist in the device storage or you can use other options like fromBytes(byte[]) or fromStream(InputStream).

Another option is you can download and load the file.

If you opt live rendering then go for another options like [Pdfjs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37361398/4238189) etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can load pdf from stream using `Executors` from `java.util.concurrent` package like this on kotlin lang:

```
val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
val url = "https://document_url.pdf"

executor.execute {
    val input = URL(url).openStream()
    handler.post {
        pdfView.fromStream(input).load()
    }
}
```